# Different method of switching pages hub class in VS C# Windows Universal

Tags: c#, navigation, controls, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

So, this may seem rather basic, but so far, the only method I've found in C# for switching the current page in windows universal app is to use the header clicked method combined with setting the IsHeaderInteractive to true. this doesn't look or feel very intuitive considering it just sticks in the little "see more" button that you click on. Rather, how would I go about adding a click event to the entire hub section that changes the page. Here's what I have right now.

```
         private void HubSection_Click(object sender, HubSectionHeaderClickEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.Section.Name)
        {
            case "China":
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(SubtopicPage));
                break;
            case "Japan":
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(SubtopicPage));
                break;
        }

    }
```

here's the XAML as well:

```
  <Page
x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}">
    <Hub Header="Countries App" Foreground="#FFC3BFBF" SectionHeaderClick="HubSection_Click" Name="CountryHub">
        <HubSection x:Name="China" MinWidth="256" Height="460" Background="#FF343434" Header="China" IsHeaderInteractive="True">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="460" Width="256" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Image Source="Assets/chinaFlag.bmp"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>

        <HubSection x:Name ="Japan" MinWidth="256" Height="460" Background="#FF565454" Header="Japan" IsHeaderInteractive="True">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="460" Width="256" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Image Source="Assets/japanFlag.bmp" Height="169"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Width="256" Height="460" Background="#FF343434">

        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Width="256" Height="460" Background="#FF565454">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="460" Width="256" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>


</Grid>
```

currently two of the four hub sections don't have content, but that's beside the point. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with RicardoPons, as I known there is no method to get selected item.

As a work round, You can add `Tabbed` event of the `HubSection`. You can know which `HubSection` was tapped.

For example:

```
<Hub Header="Countries App" Foreground="#FFC3BFBF" SectionHeaderClick="HubSection_Click" Name="CountryHub">
    <HubSection x:Name="China" MinWidth="256" Height="460" Background="#FF343434" Header="China" IsHeaderInteractive="True" Tapped="{x:Bind HubSectionTapped}">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="460" Width="256" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Image Source="Assets/dog.jpg" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>

    <HubSection x:Name ="Japan" MinWidth="256" Height="460" Background="#FF565454" Header="Japan" IsHeaderInteractive="True" Tapped="{x:Bind HubSectionTapped}">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="460" Width="256" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Image Source="Assets/color.jpg" Height="169" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

In code behind:

```
private void HubSectionTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hubSectiona = sender as HubSection;
    var name = hubSectiona.Name;
    NaviagteMethod(name);
}

public void NaviagteMethod(string name)
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case "China":
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(SubtopicPage));
            break;

        case "Japan":
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(SubtopicPage));
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for now it is the only way.

I read the official article in MSDN documentation it seems there is not an event or property to get the current selected item.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1